# Handling DBNull exception in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, error-handling

I'm trying to handle `DBNull` exception while reading data from database.
It's my code:

```
...
Dim SQLRDAs SqlDataReader
...
val1= GetStringFromDB(Trim(SQLRD("Name")))
val2= GetStringFromDB(Trim(SQLRD("Level")))
val2= GetStringFromDB(Trim(SQLRD("blahblah")))
...
Public Function GetStringFromDB(ByVal inputValue) As String
     Dim outputValue As String

     If IsDBNull(inputValue) Then
         outputValue = "null"
     Else
         outputValue = inputValue
     End If

     Return outputValue
End Function
```

But still I get `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.` error. What's wrong?

Comment: You have inverted the test for IsDBNull

Comment: Even I tried val1= IIf(IsDBNull(DS("blahblah")), "null", Trim(DS("blahblah"))) and I get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsDBNull checks if a value is missing. It is not equivalent to Nothing or to String.Empty. 
Are you sure that your inputValue contains DBNull.Value?

I will change your code in this way:

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputValue) OrElse IsDBNull(inputValue) Then 
     outputValue = "null"
```

Also note that you don't specify the type of inputValue, in my answer I assume **As String**

Comment: InputValue must not be specified with Option Strict Off. However, it could be DbNull and thats where Trim fails in the first place.

Comment: Not the problem. It is the Trim that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me than a simple transposition error. You check for `Not IsDbNull(..)` but act like the value would be dbnull!

```
Public Function GetStringFromDB(ByVal inputValue) As String
   Dim outputValue As String

   If Not IsDBNull(inputValue) Then
       outputValue = inputValue
   Else
       outputValue = "null"
   End If

   Return outputValue
End Function
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: sorry it was  If IsDBNull(inputValue) Then originally. it does not work

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed the condition.

Change

```
 If Not IsDBNull(inputValue) Then
     outputValue = "null"
 ' ....
```

To

```
 If IsDBNull(inputValue) Then
     outputValue = "null"
 ' ....
```

**Edit**: `Trim` is executed before your DBNull-check. So i assume that that's causing your exception. Change your code to:

```
GetStringFromDB(SQLRD("Name")).Trim
```

Comment: sorry it was If IsDBNull(inputValue) Then originally. it does not work

Comment: @ maysam your welcome. I thought Tim had edited his answer before mine thats why I left the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as if you try to `Trim` a `DBNull` value.

Either do `GetStringFromDB(SQLRD("Name")).Trim()` or inside `GetStringFromDB`

Edit: I'd wrap such stuff into an Extension, makes it easier to use and doesn't clutter your code.

```
  <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
  Public Function ReadString(ByVal this As SqlDataReader, ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Return If(Convert.IsDBNull(this.Item(index)), String.Empty, DirectCast(this.Item(index), String))
   End Function

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ReadString(ByVal this As SqlDataReader, ByVal columnName As String) As String
        Return If(Convert.IsDBNull(this.Item(columnName)), String.Empty, DirectCast(this.Item(columnName), String))
    End Function
```

Comment: Yes, I was my fault to Trim DBNull.